# How can I modify class .item-native inside ion-item?

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, sass

I am trying to modify class .item-native from ion-item but nothing works. I know that .item-native is what is making my map having a low height.
If its not possible to modify .item-native what could I do to increase the size of my map?

Here's my scss file:

```
ion-item {
    .item-native {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

```
 <ion-item class="abrir-mapa">
        <div class="abrir-mapa" #map id="map"></div> 
      </ion-item>
```

Tried this too.

```
.abrir-mapa {
    height: 25rem;

    .item-native {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, this is due to the annoying "Shadow DOM".

Comment: I could fix it by changing in the index.html from http:// to https:// for it to work on device.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Instead of putting ion-item I just replaced it to div with this.

```
.abrir-mapa {
    height: 25rem;
    width: 100%;
}
```